# Price issue while customers does reorder in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website, reorder

I have a multiwebsite site. Retail and wholesale.
When my customer places an order on wholesale site, the order is placed properly. When they reoder the same order from the retail site, it shows the retail site price and not the wholesale site price. Refer https://nimb.ws/tcALJD https://nimb.ws/pJIitm https://nimb.ws/iObs2u

What is going wrong here? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: have you made any customisation regarding the price chages after or before add to cart product? If yes please comment that and check again.

Comment: No i have not done any customisation.